# PHPExcel - all functions return nulls

Tags: phpexcel

I can't get any values from a spreadsheet.

```
$sheet->getCell('C10')->getOldCalculatedValue();
$sheet->getCell('C10')->getCalculatedValue();
$sheet->getCell('C10')->getValue();
```

all return null.

When I open the spreadsheet, I can see a value in the cell.
The spreadsheet is set to automatically calculate formulas.

Anything else I can try?

Mick

Comment: Well perhaps cell C10 is empty..... but without a lot more information, I can't really help you any more than that

Comment: What type of file is it? Were there any errors loading the file? Are you looking at the correct worksheet? What value do you expect to see in the cell? Consider the question you've asked, and whether you can really expect anybody to be able to answer it based on the complete lack of information that you have provided